# Using a secure web service from iPhone with SOAP

Tags: iphone, soap, ssl, https

I'm trying to get secure web service connectivity on the iPhone over https via SOAP. Currently have http working with NSMutableURLRequest but it doesn't appear to support https. Any ideas what to use to get the secure web service access and processing I'm after?

Any help appreciated // :)

Comment: HTTPS is definitely supported by the URL loading system on iPhone. What leads you to believe that it's not? Can you maybe post some code / error messages?

Comment: Not in the docs for NSMutableURLRequest? Do you have some code to point me at? Thanks //:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gSOAP. It's a C/C++ library providing fast and secure access to web services; you can even develop your own. Even though it's not natively supporting Objective C, it's still IMHO the best open source web services library. Additional information and download can be found [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)