# securing a WCF service for consumption by iphone

Tags: iphone, .net, wcf, security, authentication

I have a WCF service that needs to be secured to be consumed by an iphone app. I would like to know what my options are. I looked around the net and found that using SSL or api key or username/password over SSL is an option but I wasn't able to find any links about how to properly implement them for consumption by an iphone app. I'd really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - SSL connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716610/iphone-ssl-connection)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244764/iphone-web-service-calls-to-wcf-service-with-certificate-authentication, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584063/using-a-secure-web-service-from-iphone-with-soap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the WCF service for basicHttp binding and transport security. To make the client side of things work, you will need to implement an NSUrlConnection delegate. The phone will then be able to authenticate correctly. You can use the Keychain to store the user's credentials.

Stay away from the WS-* protocols that are typically turned on by wsHttp binding. These greatly increase the complexity of the XML you need to read and/or generate.

Although the phone can receive and send XML, it's not nearly as convenient as in .NET. You might want to consider a simpler serialization format such as JSON. This will require the use of webHttp binding.